# How to implement customizable horizontal calendar?

Tags: flutter

I need to implement a calendar view with a single information like in the image attached. Is there any decent package that is highly customizable as well ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you can usually find whatever you want if you spend some time googling. Here's a package that looks like what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar. Here's another one that includes an hourly view: https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view. Try googling "flutter calendar" along with some other keywords to find a calendar that's suitable for your needs.